# CUFON Image Replacement

Tags: fonts, embedding

I had used the CUFON image replacement for one of the site.The following is the api link
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/api
in that they say

Using `Cufon.replace()` with CSS selectors

```
Cufon.replace('#message');
Cufon.replace('h2');
Cufon.replace('#content > h3');
```

when i tried its not working

can anyone help me how to achive this

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a JavaScrtipt library that enables CSS selectors - otherwise Cufon only selects regular elements like h1, h2, li, etc - have look here  https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/usage